# Generate input (x) amount of questions from a list of questions

Tags: c++

I apologize for asking this, but I am still very, very new to programming, but I am learning. I am currently learning what 'arrays' are in C++.
 I've searched around to see how my problem would fit, but I saw only *similar* threads and not the specific ones I need for. I highly apologize, once again.

I was given a task to make a program, preferably C++, that does the following:

- Let's say I have a question bank of 25 questions.
- I would like to generate x amount of questions from that question bank.
- The 'x' is the input number that the user has to give. The program asks "How many questions would you like printed out?" Here, the user will write a number between 1 to x. If the 'x' is *bigger* than the amount of questions in the question bank, meaning bigger than 25, the program will close / or go back to the starting point (preferred)

*Hard part (I would like it, although not really needed, wondering if it is possible.)*

- The question bank can be updated. Meaning, if the bank *had* 25 questions, and the next day it has 30, the program will automatically read that the 'x' mustn't go above 30.

The idea behind the question bank would be that each question will be separated by a new line. Each time a new question is added, the user will at either the beginning or the ending of the question bank will write the *exact* number of questions that are inside the bank. That number would be 'x', and that's how the program would recognize how many questions the user can generate.

IF the idea above, about the question bank is impossible, then please say so.

I am not sure how to go about making this question bank, so I hope this gets answered as well.

I apologize for asking this, but I need to find out how to do this. I also apologize for not giving a starting code, but I am honestly not sure how to start it, considering as mentioned above, I am still learning. I know this is a bit too hard for a newbie to try out, but I need this by tomorrow. I am not asking you to make the code all by yourself if you can't, an explanation or guide on how it would be possible helps quite a lot.

Thank you very, very much if you find the time to help me make this.

Comment: How is the *question bank* defined?  Is it hard-coded?  Is it read from a file?  This is needed to answer the *hard part* of the question.

Comment: Same question as @ThomasMatthews, but also, how is the question bank updated? User input? Auto-generated from a larger list of possible questions?

Comment: Thank you for helping out. The question bank is read from a file. I apologize for not adding it. The question bank is updated from user input. The questions will be added by the user inside the file, and the program will read from that specific file.

Answer (score 0):

If the question bank is read from the file, the file could contain on its first line the amount of the questions. So, the file could look like this:

```
30 //-> the bank has 30 questions
question1
question2
...
question30
```

The value 30 will be read from the file and stored in some variable. Each time you start the program, the variable will be initialized with the updated value in the file.

If you are not allowed to write the amount of questions in the file, you could find it by reading the number of lines in the file (assuming one question is followed by newline).